# Копирование Html в модальное окно js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Здравствуйте не очень шарю в JS.Есть карточки товаров и есть один попап на все. Нужно чтоб при открытии в попап копировался блок с инфо о товаре.
Подскажите как реализовать.
У меня получается скопировать но копируется со всех карточек, а нужно чтоб копировалось с той карточки на которой вызывается попап.

```js
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-link');
const popupBody = document.querySelector('.popup');
const popupContent = document.querySelector('.popup__content');
const popupCloseIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__close');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const productCard = document.querySelectorAll('.product__card');
const productCardInfo = document.querySelectorAll('.product__card-inner');

let unlock = true;

const timeout = 300;


if (productCard.length > 0) {

    productCard.forEach(productCardItem => {

        productCardInfo.forEach(productInfo => {
            popupLinks.forEach(popupLink => {

                popupLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                    const cloneProductCardInfo = productInfo.cloneNode(true);

                    popupContent.prepend(cloneProductCardInfo);

                    if (popupBody) {
                        popupOpen(popupBody);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    });

}
if (popupCloseIcon.length > 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < popupCloseIcon.length; index++) {
        const el = popupCloseIcon[index];
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            popupBody.classList.remove('popup-active');
            popupContent.classList.remove('content-active');
            body.classList.remove('lock');
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.popupContent);
        });
    }
}

function popupOpen(popupBody) {
    if (popupBody) {
        const popupActive = document.querySelector('.popup-active');
        popupBody.classList.add('popup-active');
        popupContent.classList.add('content-active');
        body.classList.add('lock');

        popupBody.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (!e.target.closest('.popup__content')) {
                popupClose(e.target.closest('#popup'));

            }
        });
    }


}

function popupClose(popupActive) {
    if (unlock) {
        popupActive.classList.remove('popup-active');
        popupContent.classList.remove('content-active');
        body.classList.remove('lock');

    }
}
```

```css
.product__grid-template {
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 300px));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(203 212 213 / 96%);
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.product__card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247, 0.9);
}

.product__card-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product__card-image img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.hover-image {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-image:hover .hover-image {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-image:hover img.main-img,
.product__card-image:hover img.main-img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-inner {}

.product__card-title {
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product__card-info {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
}

.product__description {
    padding: 10px;
}

.product__description span {
    display: block;
}

.product__card-price {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.product__card-price p {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: rgb(255, 16, 16);
}

.product__card-button,
.btn {
    background-color: rgb(55, 73, 151);
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product__card-button:hover,
.btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(115, 115, 194);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product__card-button a {
    color: #ffffffff;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popup-active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.popup__content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 420px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 258, 267, 0.885);
    color: #000000;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, -100%);
    z-index: 10;
    height: 0;
}

.content-active {
    height: 100%;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0%);
}

.popup__close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 97%;
    background-color: #ffffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: red 2px solid;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__close:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffffff;
    border-color: #ffffffff;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__title {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.popup__img {
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.popup__img img {
    text-align: center;
}

.popup__price {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
}

.popup__price p {
    padding: 5px;
}

.form__body {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.form__body label {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    top: 14px;
    left: 3%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.input__name-body,
.input__number-body {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type='text'],
input[type='number'] {
    width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

input:focus+label {
    transform: translate(-10%, -200%) scale(0.9);
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
[type="number"]:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
    transform: translate(-10%, -200%) scale(0.9);
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.popup__btn {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn {
    color: rgb(225, 226, 236);
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popup__info {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="product__grid-template">
                <div class="product__card">

                    <div class="product__card-image">
                        <img class="main-img" src="img/bottle-dekor.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class='hover-image' src="img/bottle-dekor.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-inner">
                        <div class="product__card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-title">декоративное украшение для барной стойки</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__card-info">
                            <div class="product__description">
                                <p class='card-description'>Cтеклянная черная бутылка на качающейся подставке с узорами - летящими золотыми пегасами.
                                    <!--<span>-->Выглядит необычно и шикарно!
                                    <!--</span>-->Пегас - символ превосходства, мощи, силы, скорости, свободы и красоты!
                                    <!--<span>-->Это изделие будет прекрасным подарком ручной работы для ценителей эксклюзивных предметов интерьера.
                                    <!--</span>-->Изделие с подставкой 52х21 см. Вес 3.7кг.Объемом 4.5л.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product__card-price">
                                <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
                        <a href="#">Купить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__card">

                    <div class="product__card-image">
                        <img class="main-img" src="img/bottles.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class='hover-image' src="img/bottles.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-inner">
                        <div class="product__card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-title">денежные бутылочки</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__card-info">
                            <div class="product__description">
                                <p class='card-description'>Такой подарок принесет вам процветание и удачу!Бутылочки красивы и необычны, подойдут к любому празднику и юбилею! Такой подарок удивит и порадует ваших близких!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product__card-price">
                                <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
                        <a href="#">Купить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__card">

                    <div class="product__card-image">
                        <img class="main-img" src="img/kopilka.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class='hover-image' src="img/kopilka.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-inner">
                        <div class="product__card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-title">копилка для мальчика</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__card-info">
                            <div class="product__description">
                                <p class='card-description'>
                                    Копилка для мальчика. Выполнена на заказ.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product__card-price">
                                <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
                        <a href="#">Купить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__card">

                    <div class="product__card-image">
                        <img class="main-img" src="img/ng-venok.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class='hover-image' src="img/ng-venok.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-inner">
                        <div class="product__card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-title">новогодний венок на дверь</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product__card-info">
                            <div class="product__description">
                                <p class='card-description'>Новогодний венок на дверь/стену. Диаметр 30см. При изготовлении использованы искуственные ветки, ёлочные шары, шишки сосновые, искуственные серебряные листья.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product__card-price">
                                <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
                        <a href="#">Купить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">

        <div class="popup__body">
            <div class="popup__content">
                <div class="popup__close">X</div>
                <!-- <h3 class="popup__title">название товара</h3> -->
                <!-- <div class="popup__img">
                    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
                </div> -->
                <!-- <div class="popup__price">
                    <p>Цена:</p>
                    <p>10000 р.</p>
                </div> -->
                <div class="popup__form">
                    <form action="#" class="form__body">
                        <div class="input__name-body">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Введите Имя">
                            <label for="name" class="input__name">Введите Имя</label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="input__number-body">
                            <input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Номер телефона">
                            <label for="number" class="input__number">Номер телефона</label>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__btn">
                    <a href="" class="btn">Отправить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__info">
                    <h3>Мы перезвоним Вам в ближайшее время.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Объяснять, что именно я сделал, довольно долго и вы наверняка не поймете в письменной форме, вам проще будет свой и мой код сравнить.

```js
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-link');
const popupBody = document.querySelector('.popup');
const popupContent = document.querySelector('.popup__content');
const popupContentProducCard = document.querySelector('.popup__content--clone-product-card');
const popupCloseIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__close');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const productCard = document.querySelectorAll('.product__card');

let unlock = true;

const timeout = 300;

if (productCard.length > 0) {
  productCard.forEach((productCardItem) => {
    const productInfo = productCardItem.querySelector('.product__card-inner');
    const popupLink = productCardItem.querySelector('.popup-link');

    popupLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      const cloneProductCardInfo = productInfo.cloneNode(true);
      popupContentProducCard.innerHTML = '';
      popupContentProducCard.append(cloneProductCardInfo);

      if (popupBody) {
        popupOpen(popupBody);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
}
if (popupCloseIcon.length > 0) {
  for (let index = 0; index < popupCloseIcon.length; index++) {
    const el = popupCloseIcon[index];
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      popupBody.classList.remove('popup-active');
      popupContent.classList.remove('content-active');
      body.classList.remove('lock');
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.popupContent);
    });
  }
}

function popupOpen(popupBody) {
  if (popupBody) {
    const popupActive = document.querySelector('.popup-active');
    popupBody.classList.add('popup-active');
    popupContent.classList.add('content-active');
    body.classList.add('lock');

    popupBody.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (!e.target.closest('.popup__content')) {
        popupClose(e.target.closest('#popup'));
      }
    });
  }
}

function popupClose(popupActive) {
  if (unlock) {
    popupActive.classList.remove('popup-active');
    popupContent.classList.remove('content-active');
    body.classList.remove('lock');
  }
}
```

```css
.product__grid-template {
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 300px));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(203 212 213 / 96%);
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.product__card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247, 0.9);
}

.product__card-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product__card-image img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.hover-image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-image:hover .hover-image {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-image:hover img.main-img,
.product__card-image:hover img.main-img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.product__card-inner {}

.product__card-title {
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product__card-info {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}

.product__description {
  padding: 10px;
}

.product__description span {
  display: block;
}

.product__card-price {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product__card-price p {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgb(255, 16, 16);
}

.product__card-button,
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(55, 73, 151);
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product__card-button:hover,
.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(115, 115, 194);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.product__card-button a {
  color: #ffffffff;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popup-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup__content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 420px;
  background-color: rgba(244, 258, 267, 0.885);
  color: #000000;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  z-index: 10;
  height: 0;
}

.content-active {
  height: 100%;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0px, 0%);
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 97%;
  background-color: #ffffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: red 2px solid;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__close:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffffff;
  border-color: #ffffffff;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.popup__title {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.popup__img {
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.popup__img img {
  text-align: center;
}

.popup__price {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
}

.popup__price p {
  padding: 5px;
}

.form__body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form__body label {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  top: 14px;
  left: 3%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.input__name-body,
.input__number-body {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type='text'],
input[type='number'] {
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

input:focus+label {
  transform: translate(-10%, -200%) scale(0.9);
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
[type="number"]:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  transform: translate(-10%, -200%) scale(0.9);
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.popup__btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn {
  color: rgb(225, 226, 236);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.popup__info {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="product__grid-template">


      <div class="product__card">
        <div class="product__card-image">
          <img class="main-img" src="img/bottle-dekor.jpg" alt="">
          <img class='hover-image' src="img/bottle-dekor.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-inner">
          <div class="product__card-title">
            <h3 class="card-title">декоративное украшение для барной стойки</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="product__card-info">
            <div class="product__description">
              <p class='card-description'>Cтеклянная черная бутылка на качающейся подставке с узорами - летящими золотыми пегасами.
                <!--<span>-->Выглядит необычно и шикарно!
                <!--</span>-->Пегас - символ превосходства, мощи, силы, скорости, свободы и красоты!
                <!--<span>-->Это изделие будет прекрасным подарком ручной работы для ценителей эксклюзивных предметов интерьера.
                <!--</span>-->Изделие с подставкой 52х21 см. Вес 3.7кг.Объемом 4.5л.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__card-price">
              <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
          <a href="#">Купить</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="product__card">
        <div class="product__card-image">
          <img class="main-img" src="img/bottles.jpg" alt="">
          <img class='hover-image' src="img/bottles.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-inner">
          <div class="product__card-title">
            <h3 class="card-title">денежные бутылочки</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="product__card-info">
            <div class="product__description">
              <p class='card-description'>Такой подарок принесет вам процветание и удачу!Бутылочки красивы и необычны, подойдут к любому празднику и юбилею! Такой подарок удивит и порадует ваших близких!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__card-price">
              <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
          <a href="#">Купить</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="product__card">
        <div class="product__card-image">
          <img class="main-img" src="img/kopilka.jpg" alt="">
          <img class='hover-image' src="img/kopilka.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-inner">
          <div class="product__card-title">
            <h3 class="card-title">копилка для мальчика</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="product__card-info">
            <div class="product__description">
              <p class='card-description'>
                Копилка для мальчика. Выполнена на заказ.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__card-price">
              <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
          <a href="#">Купить</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="product__card">
        <div class="product__card-image">
          <img class="main-img" src="img/ng-venok.jpg" alt="">
          <img class='hover-image' src="img/ng-venok.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-inner">
          <div class="product__card-title">
            <h3 class="card-title">новогодний венок на дверь</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="product__card-info">
            <div class="product__description">
              <p class='card-description'>Новогодний венок на дверь/стену. Диаметр 30см. При изготовлении использованы искуственные ветки, ёлочные шары, шишки сосновые, искуственные серебряные листья.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__card-price">
              <p>Цена: 10000 р.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product__card-button popup-link">
          <a href="#">Купить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup">

  <div class="popup__body">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <div class="popup__close">X</div>
      <div class="popup__content--clone-product-card">
        <!-- <h3 class="popup__title">название товара</h3> -->
        <!-- <div class="popup__img">
                    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
                </div> -->
        <!-- <div class="popup__price">
                    <p>Цена:</p>
                    <p>10000 р.</p>
                </div> -->
      </div>

      <div class="popup__form">
        <form action="#" class="form__body">
          <div class="input__name-body">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Введите Имя">
            <label for="name" class="input__name">Введите Имя</label>

          </div>
          <div class="input__number-body">
            <input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Номер телефона">
            <label for="number" class="input__number">Номер телефона</label>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="popup__btn">
        <a href="" class="btn">Отправить</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popup__info">
        <h3>Мы перезвоним Вам в ближайшее время.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```